# Regular expression to extract hostname from fully qualified domain name

Tags: regex

I am VERY rusty with regular expressions and need one to extract a hostname from a fully qualified domain name (FQDN), here's an example of what I have:

```
myhostname.somewhere.env.com
myotherhostname.somewhereelse.insomeotherplace.byh.info
```

and I want to return

```
myhostname
myotherhostname
```

Would really appreciate some help

I tried `"(.+)\."` but it matched the string from the right and produced:

```
myhostname.somewhere.env.
myotherhostname.somewhereelse.insomeotherplace.byh.
```

Comment: What programming language are you dealing with? It would probably be less resource intensive to just split the string on `.` and return the first element than to invoke a regex engine.

Comment: In any case, the pattern you want is `^([^.]+)\..*$`

Comment: Actually it is Microsoft Excel 2007, and I added the RegExFind Add-in from here http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php I have a column in Excel with that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this regexepression `(.+?)(?=\.)`

Comment: What about 'aaa.bbb.co.uk' - that would yield 'aaa.bbb.co' which is not right.

Comment: @Paul Beckingham, you wrong, it return array matches `aaa`, `bbb` and `co` or one match `aaa`

Comment: Your solution does not truncate protocols, which should not be part of a hostname-yielding solution.

Answer (score 3):

you want the first group from:

```
([^.]*).*
```

or alternatively, the first match from:

```
[^.]*
```

or alternatively, the only match from:

```
^[^.]*
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you just need to add a `?` to make it not greedy. Just choose the first group in your match

```
(.+?)\.
```

However, as some already suggested, you probably should just split on a `.` and grab the first item from the split array. Regexes can be costly

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
^(\w+)(\.\w+)*$
```

You can test it at [regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: "-" (dash or hyphen) is a valid domain name character, and not normally matched by \w

Answer (score 0):

```
host.split('.').last(2).join('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[^.]+/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/jW3lC5/1

Reads: start of line followed by 1 or more non-period characters. 'g' for global (multiple matches), 'm' for 'multiline mode' which will make the first `^` match at the start of each line.